# nginx: strip www from unknown hostname

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect users that access a url hosted on my nginx that start with www.

as we server multiple domains that are proxied to the same app backend we are using a wildcard server block (e.g. `server_name *;`) so just using a separate www-server-block would not work.

Comment: Can you use a default server block instead of wild card, so that a regex or www.* server block could be used? See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.

Comment: thanks, could work. I'll try this.